# Django app failing on Vercel even when following tutorial video

Tags: django, deployment, vercel

I am trying to get a very basic Django app running on Vercel. I am following this tutorial and am following it almost exactly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjVzHcXCeMU&t=930s

But I just get that the serverless function crashed and a 500 error.
You can see it here: https://django-vercel-exmaple.vercel.app/

When I check the logs in Vercel, it says:

`Unknown application error occurred Runtime.Unknown`

I tried changing the install command to `pip install -r requirements.txt` (which the tutorial video didn't have to do it seems).

Comment: same problem here, were you able to find a solution?